# Images not deploying on github-pages or liveserver/run webpack

Tags: javascript, github

I've been unable to load an image (**logo.png**) with git-pages since im using webpack, so i tried to see i could just see it on my local. Seems like it doesnt work either.
I did use import, and downloaded the dependencies.

The structure of my project to visualize where could be the issue :

- dist (*folder*)

  - index.html
  - main.js (*bundled from index.js generated with webpack*)
- src (*folder*)

  - images (folder) > *logo.png*
  - scripts (folder) > *header.js*
- index.js

Here is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader:'url-loader',
                options:{
                  limit:8192,
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
      },
};
```

My **package.json file** :

```
{
  "name": "test-stackover",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

My **header.js** file (inside de src folder) :

```
import iconLogo from '/src/images/logo.png';

const createElement = (type, attributes, ...children) => {
    const element = document.createElement(type);

    for (let key in attributes) {
        element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key])
    }
    
    children.forEach(child => {
        if(typeof child === 'string'){
            element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child));
        }else{
            element.appendChild(child);
        }
    });

    return element;
}

const createHeader = () =>{

    // logo
    const imgLogo = createElement('img', {src: iconLogo, alt:'logo'},'');
    /* const imgLogo = createElement('img', {src: {iconLogo}, alt:'logo'},''); didnt work */
    const aLogo = createElement('a',{href : '#', class : 'logo'}, imgLogo);


    document.body.appendChild(aLogo);
}

export{ createHeader };
```

My **index.js** file :

```
import { createHeader } from './script/header.js';

createHeader();
```

and finally the HTML file, the script is from my bundle :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I hope i gave enough detailled infos about the issues ?

Comment: You need to `require` / `import` the image assets so Webpack bundles them

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images not loading Webpack/Webpack-dev-serve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51680955/283366)

Comment: i tried to do what was advised in your link but it didnt work

Comment: Please reformat your question so that we at stackoverflow can easily reproduce the problem and help you fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i re-edited my message, i think with all the infos given one could reproduce my error.